# Check current image being displayed on page

Tags: php

I currently have this code:

```
$img_dir = 'tsimgs/';


$images = array();


$files = scandir($img_dir);

foreach($files as $f) {
    $extension = end(explode('.',$f));
    if($extension == 'jpg') {
        $images[] = $f;
    }
    elseif($extension == 'png') {
        $images[] = $f;
    }
}

$random = array_rand($images);
$chosen = $images[$random];

if(end(explode('.',$chosen)) == 'jpg') {
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_dir.$chosen);
}
elseif(end(explode('.',$chosen)) == 'png') {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($img_dir.$chosen);
}

// WRITE OUT THE IMAGE //
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image, NULL, 100);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Basically this displays a random image on webpage visit. How would I make a script to check which image is currently being displayed to the user. Is that even possible?

Comment: What do you mean *check which image is currently being displayed*?

Comment: I mean, it displays a random image from a folder when you visit the page. How do I check which image is being displayed to the user?

Comment: Check the $image variable. That's the image being displayed.

Comment: I think the real question should be where/when are you wanting to check? If it's in this file, then the answer is simply too obvious. If it's in another file, well, we are going to need a lot more information.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a perfect solution, but if you are already using sessions you could set a session variable when selecting the image to show to the user, and then fetch it when you want to know which image is being displayed.

You have to remember though, that if the user has multiple windows open there is no guarantee that this works.